# .net load configuration in class library

Tags: vb.net, class-library

let's say i have :
1) 1 WindowsForm on "A" Project
2) 1 WindowsForm on "B" Project
3) 1 class library (GAC)

**Condition**
Both of Project references is same

**Part 1 :**
I have my.settings in my class library to save configuration with public function

**Part 2 :**
I create value/configuration from "A" and store it in my class library.
settings has been successfully saved, and load the value/configuration with no errors

**Question :**
1). Why i can't load the value/configuration from "B" ? *NullException shown*
First I think, to use my.resources in class library but, my.resources is readonly

2). What best solution to connecting 1 class library to multiple project

**code in class library to save value**

```
Public Sub Kucing_simpan(ByVal value As String)
    My.Settings.Kucing = value
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

**code in class library to load value**

```
Public Function kucing_ambil()
    Dim value As String
    value = My.Settings.Kucing
    Return value
End Function
```

**code in "A"**

```
dim save as new Zombie.Kencing 'My class Library Name
save.Kucing_simpan(textbox1.text)
```

**code in "B"**

```
dim load as new Zombie.Kencing 'My class Library Name
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = load.kucing_ambil
```

Comment: each app (from A Prj and B Prj) has their own My.Settings object, why not use them?  *What* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want store the value/configuration in class library with "A" project, so "B" or "C" or "D" project can get the value/conf from class library.. like this, "A" save the value to class library, and "B" load the value, is that possible??

Comment: at the least, you will need one big pool of settings; the Class Lib wont partition them into ones for A, some for B etc nor can it get A's settings for A.  The CLassLib also wont load them to A's my.settings, they will be the DLL's.  And you will have to expose props for every single setting.  Better, IMO, to add a class to manage them all which is shared among A, B, C and D which can also manage saving and loading for you.

Comment: The Settings Object in Class Library sir not "A" Project, assignment of "A" is to change value in

Comment: I realize that; I am saying the Lib cant load them for A or into A's Settings.  `Why i can't load the value/configuration from "B"` [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26076985/edit) to show the code which fails; we have no idea what the code looks like

Comment: That's my code sir, please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do what you are trying to do - at least not the way you are going about it.

First, you have to understand how/where Settings are saved.  With default naming of the app and such, project A - `WindowsApplication1` will save its settings to something cryptic such as:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\_
    WindowsApplication1_Url_ggn13vigzyicmtfkwaa3vi5tyxn0sy3r\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

NET creates the hash to make sure that apps with the same name have a different safe location to store settings.  So, `WindowsApplication3` will have a different hash; this is also how your 17th project with the name  `WindowsApplication1` doesnt accidentally load or find the settings of WinApp 1-16.

Next, your Settings Class Lib is not a separate application.  As a DLL, it is operating as if it was a set of functions and such associated with the App calling it.  So when Project A saves settings thru the ClassLib, they are saved to a different location than Project B.  Even using a Class Lib, NET uses **Application** credentials and info to concoct the filename and path.

---

What you *can* do is write a Class which defines all the possible settings (or creates a `List` or `Dictionary` of them) then save to a fixed, known location such as:

```
Private Comp As String = "ZiggySoft"
Private Prod As String = "ZiggyWare"

Private settingsFile As String

'...
settingsfile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
settingsfile = Path.Combine(settingsfile, Comp, Prod, "usersettings.dat")
```

This will result in:
     "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ZiggySoft\ZiggyWare\usersettings.dat"

Include the same file in each project (Add Existing Item, maybe pick Add As Link from the dropdown).  Now, you can read and write your Settings to a file you are in charge of.  You can save/load the entire class or List in 3-5 lines of code if you serialize it.

When Project A loads the settings, it would also get those which only apply to B or J or V, but common ones would and could be shared.